# Gui text does not display

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui

I am using unity 4.6 to develop a small game. 
There is no gui text object in the menu. Therefore I created an empty object and added gui text as a component. But it does not display the text I type. Need help on this. Thank you

Comment: make sure gui text have a font or not

Comment: Try to check the size & color of the font

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. All helped me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that 4.6 is when they introduced the new UI system so you can use that.It is actually pretty easy...from the drop down menu that you created the game object go to UI. There you can select from a number UI options one of witch is Text or UI Text if my memory serves me well. When you click it it will create a canvas object and UI Text object that is a child of the Canvas.From here just select the Text object and in the inspector you have a textbox which should serve your need :) Also the Canvas is your screen in the sense that if you drag your text to the top left corner of the Canvas(in the scene view) your text will be in the top left corner of the screen when you start your game(at least in the default settings). Hope that helps!

P.S. Also here is a link to the new UI article that the Unity guys have on their site: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/the-new-ui

Answer (score 1):

That happens sometimes. Delete the current gameobject and the guitext in the scene. Do what you did **backwards**.

Create a **new guitext** then **create a new empty gameobject**. **Change** the **transform** of the **empty** **gameobject** to **0,0,0** then drag the **new gui text** into the **empty** **gameobject**.

That should solve your problem.
The default text you should see if that went well is "New Text".

If you are editing the new text in the text area and it stopped showing, you will need to increase the **width** and sometimes the **Height** of the guiText. **Don't use the scale tool** as that **will work** but the graphics you get will be **low quality** text rendering on the screen.